# How to authenticate user without inputing username or password?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a project for school, it's a simple online shop with cart and admin management build with PHP and MySQL database. In the database I have admin table and users table. The users table contains 3 users, user1, user2, user3. Now I want the user to scan a QR code and be able to purchase from the shop.

So let's say user1 scans the code and orders something, in the admin panel I you will see what user1 order.

In short, I want the user to scan a QR Code to authenticate to the website in order to make a purchase.

Sorry if the question is not understandable.

Comment: "I want" is not actually a question, but yes we understand what you wrote. Basically you would need a unique QR code per user, probably created when they first sign up. But I'm not sure it's the most secure kind of token - it's easy to copy if you happen to get sight of it.

Comment: If your QR code has query string params that are usable more than once, you may find that you've introduced a security issue.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry it's not a question but you get my point. So basically I need a token system?

Comment: well in your design the user's QR code _is_ the token. My point was only that it's not a very secure one. QR codes weren't intended to act as security tokens. They're easy to copy, and also easy to decode. All that happens is the device decodes the QR code, turns it into a URL and then visits that URL. So your URL would have to include something to identify the user. Once that URL is known, _anyone_ can visit that URL and impersonate the user, without even having directly seen the QR code.

Comment: I know this is just for school but I don't see much point in learning something which isn't at least vaguely realistic. In my opinion your time would be better spent learning about the various kinds of security normally applied to web applications. The other thing about authentication systems is never to create your own (unless that becomes your field of study or expertise) - always use a ready-made, tested platform. If you're studying security specifically, then QR is not a good solution. If you aren't studying security specifically, use a ready-made solution and spend your effort elsewhere.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- I think your users table should contain a column with a token.
- That token should be printed in the QR code
- You scan the value with a scanner and retrieve the user from the db

I think this is nice for a school project, but very weak security for a real webshop

Comment: So I just need to create a token column, implement it with a QR code and then check which token corresponds with which user and make a session with it? And yes it's weak but I don't need real security because it's a school project.

Comment: It's not weak security, it's a complete absence of security. A QR code is nothing but a URL encoded as a picture. Once you've either copied the QR code (easy enough) or seen what URL it leads to, you have access to the user's account. I could possibly see how a QR code could be provided as a convenience method as part of a more comprehensive authentication system, but this approach is incredibly naive. I'm not sure even a school project would see this as a credible solution if the project is to build a web shop where, by implication, money is meant to change hands (even if only in theory)

Answer (score 0):

is this what your looking for?

```
$data = User::where('qr_token', $qr_token)->first();

if ($data) {
        auth()->login($data);
    }
```

i think qr code token is not best practice for auth.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to authenticate users without requiring them to input a username or password, including:

Single Sign-On (SSO): SSO allows users to log in to multiple applications or websites with a single set of credentials. This can be done through an identity provider (IdP) such as Google, Facebook, or a company's own Active Directory.

Social Media Login: Social media login allows users to log in to an application or website using their existing social media account, such as Facebook, Google, or Twitter.

Phone Number Authentication: Phone number authentication allows users to log in to an application or website by entering their phone number and receiving a one-time code via SMS.

Email Link Authentication: Email link authentication allows users to log in to an application or website by clicking on a link sent to their email address.

Biometric Authentication: Biometric authentication allows users to log in to an application or website using their fingerprints, face recognition, or other biometric data.

Federated Identity : It allows a user to authenticate using an identity from an external identity provider, without having to create a new account specifically for the application.